# Lambda function inside render props

Tags: reactjs

I am using render props:

```
<MyComponent>
  {myProps => (
    <button onClick={({ target: { value } }) => myProps.myFunction(value)} />
  )}
</MyComponent>
```

However the `onClick={({ target: { value } }) => myProps.myFunction(value)}` is not optimized, as it creates a new function on each render.

My naive solution is:

```
const handleClick = props => ({ target: { value } }) => props.myFunction(value);

<MyComponent>
  {myProps => (
    <button onClick={handleClick(myProps)} />
  )}
</MyComponent>
```

But if I understand well, unless `handleClick` is somehow memoized then it's quite useless.

Is there a nice way to optimize lambda functions in render props?

Note: Bonus point if it only uses stateless functional components, optionally with recompose.

Comment: Have you looked into using recompose's withHandlers API? I find that having the component props available to the handler by default is really useful. https://recompose.docsforhumans.com/withhandlers.html

Comment: I saw that, but I don't know how to add a HOC like `withHandlers` on a renderProp. Can you give an example?

Comment: There's a good example here: https://medium.com/@abhiaiyer/building-a-render-prop-with-recompose-b4a03fa9606f. But as was said in the article, and I agree with, I'm not too keen on the idea of mixing HOCs and render props patterns.

Comment: wait why are you going to HOC while using render props and you could use arrow function to avoid function creation on each render

Comment: @SakhiMansoor I would like to see an example without HOC. And I didn't understand "and you could use arrow function".

Comment: your naive solution is great. What's issue with it ? you're not creating new function in it.

Comment: @SakhiMansoor Incorrect. On each render, I call `handleClick(props)`, which creates a new function `({ target: { value } }) => props.myFunction(value)`: not desired. That's why I added the memoization comment: if `props.myFunction` didn't change, the returned function reference shouldn't change neither.

Comment: no you're not creating a new function. You're doing `currying` kinda thunk here.

Comment: @SakhiMansoor https://jsbin.com/kapocehuha/edit?js,console

Comment: exactly. It is returning a function not calling it right away.